# Host a Web API under a Web Forms project

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api2

I have a ASP.NET Web APi project that uses an AngularJS as the front end. It is called "MyApiApp".

`http://localhost/MyApiApp`

I would like to move this project under another project that is an ASP.NET web forms website. It is called "MyWebForms" app.

`http://localhost/MyWebFormsApp`

My goal is to move the "MyApiApp" under the Web Forms app and access the "MyApiApp" as

`http://localhost/MyWebFormsApp/MyApiApp`

Is it possible to have an ASP.NET Web API hosted under an ASP.NET Web Forms project? I would like to be able to do this in Visual Studio where I could run that Web Forms application but have access to the "MyApiApp" app via the above URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You should be able to set it up as a virtual folder in IIS underneath the main website.

In the case of the VS Project, the built in web server doesn't support virtual folders, you'd have to set it up to run through actual IIS.

You should be able to have the WebAPI Controller as part of the main web forms project though.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I was looking to do this within Visual Studio such that I could have them in the same project. I will update my question.

Comment: In that case, the built in web server doesn't support virtual folders, you'd have to set the project up to run in actual IIS. In theory though, you should be able to have a web api controller as part of the web forms project.

Comment: @Tim Please make your answer correct to add upper comment.